# related to the camera which disorients itself when i try to follow it along the path in blender 2.8

Tags: animation

ggddaaaaaaayyyy!!!!!!! hi  i am an intermediate in blender and i am encountering a slight problem in my 2.8 beta . i know the the build is not stable right now and is in development but i am facing an issue which i think most of them might not be facing and that is when i try to attach the camera with a path to follow along it ... it gets disoriented in a way that i am unable to change it.... it doesnt happens in 2.79......but when i try to repeat the same steps i get a very wierd rotation of my camera ... not only that the cam simply throws itself into the scene in a random location...which is strange becoz i never face any such prob in 2.79.... if anyone has resolved this issue then pls share it with me as i am in need of starting cam animations in blender 2.8.....

Comment: i wish i could upload an image to demonstrate of whats happening

Comment: Could you upload a file to [blend-exchange](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting)?